# Admob page stopped shows statistics before 20 hours

Tags: android, admob

I have many android apps with Admob but when i visit the Admob page for statistics freeze (stop) for all my apps at last 20 hours.Why?I don't clicking the ads myself....The banners inside my apps works fine....shows ads!!!

Comment: I also have the same, It says "Last updated on 2013-06-08" and no reports after that.

Comment: Same problem, 0 requests, yesterday was 7000 but in apps ads are shown

Comment: Same here, house ads are also not updated. The ads are working fine, so I guess we have to wait for a fix.

Comment: For me it works now! Got my klicks and requests ! Check again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here, stats stopped updating around 5 am this morning, good to see its a common issue as of 6/8/13 my guess is that it will get resolved soon and everything will be back to normal.

Comment: In my app stopped working yesterday also, and in the app didn't appear any ad...

Answer (score 0):

I see this too. J have seen this before, it is probably an admob problem. Once they fix it, you will (most likely) see all the missing data.