# Admob doesn't record impression

Tags: android, admob

I'm testing my application in Eclipse. The problem is that when I compile and run my app I see  interstitial ads. But if I look at admob statistic - it says that I still have 0 impressions with my ad. Few days have gone.

I have checked ad unit id - it is correct.

The code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_ID);
       showAd();
    ...
 }
 public void showAd(){
     AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);

           interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
               public void onAdLoaded(){
                    displayInterstitial();
               }
           });

}
 public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adMob last a day to update. Sometimes it have lasted more like in this case:
[Admob page stopped shows statistics before 20 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006241/admob-page-stopped-shows-statistics-before-20-hours) 
Have you try in a device and cliking on it? if the interstitial is working I will not worry. Just wait.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have removed any testing devices from your code, this will cause you issues. Also as the anotherBug stated, statistics will not automatically generate the impression straight away you need to be patient unfortunately. If your ads are appearing then they are working do not worry.